AES-256 key expansion
I'm currently struggling with the implementation of my Rijndael key schedule.
My current algorithm is as follows:

Split normal key into 8 keys

Run from i = 8 to i = 60 (for 60 keys overall)

If i % 8 == 0 then rotate the last key once, substitute all the bytes in that word, XOR it with the rcon value of i / 4, else if i % 4 == 0 apply the substitution


after applying all these algorithms, XOR the resulting key t with the key 8 positions back.
Is my logic incorrect? When I make this into code, I get incorrect values.

I think that your loop should run up to 59 and that t should be XORed with the key 8 positions back rather than the last key obtained.

My bad, I am XORing with the i-8 position. But why run until 59? Am i only supposed to take the first key as the original one? for example if the master key is 00000...

00000..
whatever comes next.
Or should it be the first 8 keys being 00000.... and i run until 60, so 60-8 iterations, which is what i am running currently.?


i from 8 to 52 is 44 iterations. You are right that the first 8 words of round key are directly taken from the "master key" (words of key should then be grouped 4 at a time to make 128-bit round keys. If we call the first 8 words $W_0, W_1,\ldots, W_7$ then you should compute $W_i$ for $i\ge 8$ using the process that you describe.

I am doing this. I calcualte Wi for i>=8 until i=60, this still gives me incorrect values though, i have no clue why.

Okay.. So turns out my word substitution function was working incorrectly. and i was XORing with rcon[i/4], which for some reason had a different value rather than keeping a variable that starts with 1 (rcon[j)
Well, thank you @Daniel S for the help, I really appreciate it.
